# Adding sequence item to configuration

Tags: 8, configuration

I have a configuration item in my custom module, part of which is a sequence, basically I'm attempting to create something akin to an array of items

my_module.schema.yml

```
my_module.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'Configuration'
  mapping:
    custom_fields:
      label: 'Custom Fields'
      type: sequence
      sequence:
        type: mapping
        label: 'Custom Field'
        mapping:
          field_label:
            type: string
            label: 'Field Label'
          field_key:
            type: string
            label: 'Field Key'
```

What I want to be able to do is add a new item to this 'list' as desired, but for the most part up to now (in other areas of my module) I've just been using `$config->set(key, value)` which will just overwrite the current setting, is there a method to add another value to the existing setting, or do I have to load the existing configuration, add it in manually, then save over the whole lot?

Answer (score 0):

turns out, yes, you **can** retrieve the existing set of variables and add to it, but I'm not saying for certain that this is the correct, or best way to do it

```
// Load the current configuration and add this to it
$custom_fields = $config->get('custom_fields');
$custom_fields[] = array(
  'field_label' => 'some label',
  'field_key' => 'some_key',
);
$config->set('custom_fields', $custom_fields);
```

The above works fine, if anyone encounters this and wants to see how to do it, or anyone knows a better way, please feel free to comment